# Params between Liferay ADT and Liferay Template

Tags: templates, liferay, liferay-6, freemarker, velocity

I have an ADT writted in velocity to manage a slider of promotions. This ADT manage how the modules are going to be displayed. In other hand, I have an elements writted in freemarker to display how a single promo is shown.

The problem is the following, i have to add and onclick event in every single promo, this event has to have the position of the promo inside of the slider, but the position only is known by the ADT what is who go over the loop for the each promo.

I need to pass the foreach index from the velocity ADT to the freemarker template to can put in into the onclick event.

Is that possible? I add a little example of the problem.

**ADT**

```
<#list entries as entry>
(here I recover each promo printed by the template)
${entry_index} ---> the promo index that i have to put in the event of the promo
</#list>
```

Comment: You said that you have a velocity ADT but the snippet you posted is written in freemarker. However, maybe you can solve this using a javascript Event Listener, [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/click/) (you had to import) or [Alloy](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/working-with-the-dom-in-alloyui#handling-node-object-events) (already imported into liferay) provides usefull event listener functions.

Comment: Sorry, the ADT is written in freemarker and the template is written in velocity.
Could you post me an example of EventListener in alloy or jquery?
Thanks!

Comment: You can find full examples in both links I posted in the previous comment.